# Flutter VoIP Push notification on Android

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement kind of push notification for Video app.

On Flutter side I receive FCM Push notification and when this happens a function is call to handle code from native side.

```
onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');

        await callFromAndroid();
```

And Future function which is being called is this:

```
Future<void> callFromAndroid() async
  {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('callFromAndroid');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

And on Android side this is MainActivity which should trigger VideoActivity handler...

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "my.test";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {

                if (methodCall.method.equals("callFromAndroid")) {

                    videoActivityHandler();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void videoActivityHandler() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoCallActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


// to release screen lock
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
        keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
    }
}
```

However, when FCM notification arrives it arises empty activity. Also it is not working when app is in background or phone is locked.

I am total beginner in mobile app development and have no experience in Android Native development. All these code I found while doing research on this topic...

So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: If you are asking about native solution then not yet. Temporary I have this solution implemented in my project - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9ngriCV0J0

Answer (score 1):

I am too late, but...

If you like to receive FCM push when app is on background/terminated or even in foreground you should send `data` payload without `notification` payload. In this case you can handle notification in FCM's `onBackgroundMessage` callback.

May be someone can find it useful.